# Can a SwiftUI app control zoom under accessibility

Tags: swiftui, accessibility

Can a SwiftUI app control zoom under accessibility?

I looked under UIScreenMode availableModes and didn't see a way

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? And on what platform?

Comment: I'm trying to turn iPhone Accessibility Zoom on/off in my iOS app

Comment: You've tagged `zoom-sdk`, which is the Zoom Video SDK (the SDK behind the Zoom video conferencing software). That is not what you mean, then?

Comment: sorry... I'm asking about changing text size within my app

Comment: So are you referring to the zoom settings in accessibility or the text size? Regardless, I'm not positive, but I believe those are not controllable by your app. You can, however, read the dynamic text size, or are certainly free to display the text in whatever size you want in your own app.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the system-wide setting. It is incredibly rare to be able to modify a system wide setting (generally when this is possible, it's done in the form of an extension).

You can adjust your View hierarchy, however, by using the [`.dynamicTypeSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/dynamictypesize(_:)-1m2tf) modifier.